# Tag Synonym request: [keybindings] -> [key-bindings]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I haven't earned sufficient privileges here to make a proposal -- would it be reasonable for [keybindings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/keybindings) to be a synonym of [key-bindings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/key-bindings)?

Comment: Note: [I've raised this issue on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103168/calling-all-synonymists-we-need-your-help) as a call to synonymize.  :O)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree. They've been synonym'd and merged